# Predict label of text with multi-layered perceptron model in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm following a tutorial and can walk through the code, which trains a neural network and evaluates its accuracy.

But I don't know how to use the trained model on a new single input (string) to predicts its label.

Can you advise how this might be done?

**Tutorial:**

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/big-picture-machine-learning-classifying-text-with-neural-networks-and-tensorflow-d94036ac2274

**Session Code:**

```
# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(len(newsgroups_train.data)/batch_size)
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x,batch_y = get_batch(newsgroups_train,i,batch_size)
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            c,_ = sess.run([loss,optimizer], feed_dict={input_tensor: batch_x,output_tensor:batch_y})
            # Compute average loss
            avg_cost += c / total_batch
        # Display logs per epoch step
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "loss=", \
                "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
    print("Optimization Finished!")

    # Test model
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(output_tensor, 1))
    # Calculate accuracy
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
    total_test_data = len(newsgroups_test.target)
    batch_x_test,batch_y_test = get_batch(newsgroups_test,0,total_test_data)
    print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({input_tensor: batch_x_test, output_tensor: batch_y_test}))
```

I have some experience with Python but basically no experience in Tensorflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we need to convert the text to array:

```
def text_to_vector(text):
    layer = np.zeros(total_words,dtype=float)
    for word in text.split(' '):
        layer[word2index[word.lower()]] += 1

    return layer

# Convert text to vector so we can send it to our model
vector_txt = text_to_vector(text)
# Wrap vector like we do in get_batches()
input_array = np.array([vector_txt])
```

We can save and load models for reuse. We first create a Saver object and then save the session (after the model is trained):

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
... train the model ...
save_path = saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
```

In the example model the last "step" in the model architecture (i.e. the last thing done inside the `multilayer_perceptron` method) is:

```
'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
```

So to get a prediction we get the index of the maximum value of this array (the predicted class):

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
    print("Model restored.")

    classification = sess.run(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), feed_dict={input_tensor: input_array})
    print("Predicted category:", classification)
```

You can check the whole code here: https://github.com/dmesquita/understanding_tensorflow_nn

Answer (score 3):

Tensorflow uses declarative style of programing. You need to **declare** what you want it to do, and only afterwards invoke it's `run` or `eval` functions.

1) if you want to do some interactive tinkering with your model, you need to have `Session` handler open. Replace first lines with:

```
# Launch the graph
sess = tf.Session()
with sess.as_default():
    .......
```

Original code closes the session, and you can not continue to use the trained model anymore.
Do not forget to call `sess.close()` when you do not need it to release resources allocated to TF.

2) Now you have to convert the text you want to classify into numerical tensor representation. In original code it is done with `get_batch()`. Follow the same pattern.

3) Declare the result. Your model is associated with variable `prediction`.

4) Invoke TF.
 So the final code looks like:

```
texts = ['''By '8 grey level images' you mean 8 items of 1bit images?
It does work(!), but it doesn't work if you have more than 1bit
in your screen and if the screen intensity is non-linear.''',

'''Wanted: Shareware graphics display program for DOS.
Distribution: usa\nOrganization: University of Notre Dame, Notre Dame
Lines: 16 I need a graphics display program that can take as a parameter the name of
the file to be displayed, then just display that image and then quit.
All of the other graphics display programs come up with a menu first or some other silliness.
This program is going to be run from within another program.  '''       
        ]
# convert texts to tensors
batch = []
for text in texts:
    vector = np.zeros(total_words,dtype=float)
    for word in text.split(' '):
        if word in word2index:
            vector[word2index[word.lower()]] += 1
    batch.append(vector)

x_in = np.array(batch)

# declare new Graph node variable
category = tf.argmax(prediction,1) # choose by maximum score

# run TF
with sess.as_default():
    print("scores:", prediction.eval({input_tensor: x_in}))
    print('class:', category.eval({input_tensor: x_in}))


Out[]:
scores: [[-785.557    -781.1719    105.238686]
         [ 554.584    -532.36383   263.20908 ]]
class: [2 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

The text information needs to be converted to some numeric form to be fed to a neural network. So the above code does the following to achieve that:

#### Create a `vocabulary`:

First a dictionary of all words with a unique token is formed using the training+text set. In the code, `word2index` gives the unique token for the given word. For ex, `word2index['the']` gives the token output `10`.

**Note:** The length of the `word2index` gives the total dictionary size, and its used as the feature size in the above network.

#### Convert text to features

Given a new input string, each of the words are converted to tokens using the `word2index` dictionary and those tokens are used to populate a feature vector (which is of the size of a dictionary), with the frequency of occurrence of that particular index. The part of the code that does this:

```
 input = 'Your string ....'

 #form the input feature should be size of the dictionary len(vocab)
 feature = np.zeros(len(vocab),dtype=float)

 #Split each word and then get the token. 
 #Use this token as the index to feature vector to update the frequency of occurrence. 
 for word in input.split(' '):
    feature[word2index[word.lower()]] += 1
```

The above code should be used to generate the input to your network given a text string.

The above code has issues, one particular is: it doesnt handle out of vocabulary words (OOV). you can find details of that problem is addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45495190/initializing-out-of-vocabulary-oov-tokens).